# Yotpo <div> widget center

Tags: html, css, center

Im using a widget by Yotpo on my website and would like to center it.

Its located in a product-list.tpl so i thought that product-list.css should be the css to speak with the div.

```
<div class="yotpo bottomLine" 
data-appkey="{$yotpoAppkey}" 
data-domain="{$yotpoDomain}" 
data-product-id="{$product.id_product}"
data-product-models="" 
data-name="{$product.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" 
data-url="{$product.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" 
data-image-url="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_image, '')}" 
data-description="{$product.description_short|strip_tags:'UTF-8'|truncate:360:'...'}"
data-lang="{$yotpoLanguage|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" 
data-bread-crumbs=""> 
</div>
```

I did try this one:

```
.yotpo_bottomline .{
text-align: center!important;
}
```

But that didnt realy worked.

Comment: Use firebug to see which css class or id affect your div. Edit: in your 2nd code box; before { there is a dot, delete it and re try. Edit 2: oh well your css class name is incorrect. In your 1st code box there are 2 class assigned to your div: yotpo and bottomline. They are different classes. You assigned a new class in your css named: yotpo_bottomline. That's why you can not speak with div.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did delete the "." and also trysed .yotpo and .bottomLine with the text-align: center; (with and without !important) noone of them did change anything on the divs positioning.

Comment: Does your div contains text or image?

Comment: This is the .css of the whole yotpo plugin:
http://staticw2.yotpo.com/2Yf4sKFkGM33aigqEq1mGBD91r3nsGloU8qhMQEp/widget.css

It basicly contains text and "image" it just shows the review of the product in stars and how many reviews it got. But i have no idea how the div is called. http://evoxity.net/ is the website. And the first product got a review as you can see its on the left site and not centered

Comment: div.yotpo.bottomLine { width: 165px; margin: 0 auto; } did fix it

Answer (score 0):

I have used in-line styling to solve the issue in our collection pages on Shopify.

Use the following code in the `<div>` preceeding the main data calls from Yopto.
The padding is optional but adds a small gap from the element above.

```
<div style="margin: auto; width: 50%; padding: 5px;" class="yotpo bottomLine"
```